# db_select get value of the field

Tags: 8, database

I have order form with field reference number. when a new order is submitted i need to get the last reference number. I did something similar long time ago in Drupal 7 but now i need to do it in Drupal 8 and i don't know how. I noticed that fields in database are written as 'node__field_ref_number'

```
DRUPAL 7
$query = db_select('field_data_field_order_reference_number', 'f');
$query->condition('f.bundle', 'order', '=');
$query->fields('f', array('field_order_reference_number_value'));
$query->orderby('field_order_reference_number_value','DESC');
$query->range(0, 1);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->execute();
$record = $result->fetchAssoc();
//drupal_set_message('previous order №: ' .print_r($record['field_order_reference_number_value'], true));
$title =($record['field_order_reference_number_value']) + 1;
//drupal_set_message('order №: ' .print_r($title, true));
$form_state['node']->field_order_reference_number['und'][0]['value'] = $title;
$form_state['node']->title= 'reference number ' .$title;
```

So far i can get only nid of nods of that type (content_type_order)

```
DRUPAL 8
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'nid');
$query->condition('n.type', 'content_type_order');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
drupal_set_message('value' .print_r($results, true));
```

Comment: Take a look to this question 
 [Help with database query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266956/help-with-database-query/266961#266961)  it may give you a clue how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this snippet would get you the number:

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node__field_order_reference_number', 'f');
$query->fields('f', ['field_order_reference_number_value']);
$query->orderBy("revision_id", 'DESC');
$query->range(0, 1);
$last_order_reference_number = $query->execute()->fetchCol()[0];
```

If you need to further understand the database schema related to your field, you could try these commands:

mysql> show tables like '%order_reference_number%';

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_drupal8 (%order_reference_number%) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| node__field_order_reference_number           |
| node_revision__field_order_reference_number  |
+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> describe node__field_order_reference_number;

```
+------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle                             | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                            | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id                          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id                        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| langcode                           | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_order_reference_number_value | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

mysql> select * from  node__field_order_reference_number;

```
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+
| bundle | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | field_order_reference_number_value |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+
| page   |       0 |        17 |          28 | en       |     0 | 123                                |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
....
```

or you can try with [Drupal::entityTypeManage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.4.x)

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$entity ->condition('type','node_type');
$nids = $entity->execute();
```